# Unable to redirect to action struts1 using response.sendRedirect

Tags: jsp, struts1

My welcome file is `index.jsp` and I want to redirect to `HomeAction.do`.
So I wrote:

```
<%
    response.sendRedirect("HomeAction.do");
%>
```

But it gives 404 error. How do i get exact url? My HomeAction extends BaseAction and BaseAction extends Action.

[image]

Comment: Post your relevant action part from `struts-config.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Struts 1.x has reached [End Of Life](http://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html) status as of 2013-04-05, So it's not recommended to use 1.x version. Though you can try the code below for your issue,

In your index.jsp file use `<jsp:forward>` tag instead of scriptlets.

```
<jsp:forward page="HomeAction.do"/>
```

And in your `struts-config.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC 
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN" 
"http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>
    <action-mappings>
        <action
            path="/HomeAction"
            type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction"
            parameter="/welcomeStruts1.jsp"/>
    </action-mappings>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</struts-config>
```

See [Configure a welcome page in Struts](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/configure-a-welcome-page-in-struts/) for details. Hope this helps.

Comment: I got similar solution from my senior yesterday! Thanks anyways!

Comment: You are welcome..! Mark it as [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), so others will get the benefits of this answer.